# Script to loop through query and export results to excel

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following script which I am using to loop through a query and export the results in an excel file.

```
begin
    for months in 0..12 loop
      data_dump( query_in     => 'select count(*) from reservation where trunc(update_date) between (select add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -(months) ) from dual) and (select add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE),-(months+1)) from dual)',
                               file_in      => 'excel_'||months||'.csv',
                              directory_in => 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test',
                              delimiter_in => '|' );
     end loop;
end;
```

The data_dump is a procedure that exports the results to a excel file.

I am trying to make the formula I use dynamic like below:

```
(select add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -(months) ) from dual)
```

the `months` variable comes from the loop, but when i run the query it turns with errors.

Help with the syntax would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that problem is here:

```
'select count(*) 
from reservation 
where trunc(update_date) between 
(select add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -(months) ) from dual) 
and (select add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE),-(months+1)) from dual)'
```

In your case 'months' is just text. You need change expression in this way:

```
'select count(*) 
from reservation 
where trunc(update_date) between 
(select add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -('|| months ||') ) from dual) 
and (select add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE),-('|| months+1 ||')) from dual)'
```

Answer (score 0):

try the months like  ''||months||'' to get values dynamically